# Catch All Field in Apache Solr Not Working

Tags: solr

I am creating a custom catch-all field with a porter stemmer in Apache Solr. I want to index and query the data using this field.

First I created a field type using the following JSON

```
  {
   "add-field-type":{ 
      "name":"text_general_extended",
      "class":"solr.TextField",
      "positionIncrementGap":"100",
      "multiValued":true,
      "indexAnalyzer":{ 
         "tokenizer":{ 
            "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"
         },
         "filters":[ 
            { 
               "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
               "words":"stopwords.txt",
               "ignoreCase":"true"
            },
            { 
               "class":"solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"
            },
            { 
               "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
            }
         ]
      },
      "queryAnalyzer":{ 
         "tokenizer":{ 
            "class":"solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"
         },
         "filters":[ 
            { 
               "class":"solr.StopFilterFactory",
               "words":"stopwords.txt",
               "ignoreCase":"true"
            },
            { 
               "class":"solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"
            },
            { 
               "class":"solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory",
               "expand":"true",
               "ignoreCase":"true",
               "synonyms":"synonyms.txt"
            },
            { 
               "class":"solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Then I created a field with the above field type

```
{ 
   "add-field":{ 
      "name":"_text_extended",
      "type":"text_general_extended",
      "multiValued":true,
      "indexed":true,
      "stored":false
   }
}
```

Finally, I created a copy field and added my text field i.e. passage_text in destination '_text_extended'

```
{"add-copy-field" : {"source":"passage_text","dest":"_text_extended"}}
```

I created all the JSON using the _default configset in Solr. I am not sure what am I missing here.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Could you please share the schema.xml?

Comment: I have used the _default schema. It is exactly similar to it. Just added above custom fields...

Comment: Did you reindex your data after you defined your copy-field?

Comment: I created the copy field first and then indexed the data!

Comment: Do you have any examples of data you've indexed and what you're querying? What does the Analysis page under Solr admin say for that combination? (and just to be clear, a single `copyField` instruction isn't a catch-all, in that case you'd have the source set as `*`).

Comment: Yes, I understand copying single field does not make it a catch-all field. All I want to do is not pass the field name while querying. The field type is working properly